# Android retrieve spam numbers from sms spam folder or list

Tags: java, android, sms, adt, spam

i would like to know if it is possible to get the list of spam numbers in spam folder of SMS. Or is there any library you know that i can integrate.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. There is no message type for _spam_ in the SMS Provider, so that would make me think that the numbers are stored internally by the SMS app itself. Have you seen an app before with the functionality you describe?